# What is a word to describe a response to a question that is evasive but not untrue

Tags: single-word-requests, questions

I'm looking for a single word synonym of evasion, fudging or dodging the question that does not imply deceit in the answer (apart from possible awareness of the respondent that they are not actually answering the question, and perhaps an intent to divert the questioner to other topics).

Answers could be verbose or blunt non-sequiturs.

This is similar but not identical to *"What do you call a response which does not address the question?"* There answers have other connotations, such as a word or phrase for an inappropriate response (such as a "non sequitur"). This is a new question, which differs particularly in that I'm looking for a word that does not imply an intention to deceive.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the situation? Maybe include an example?

Comment: An answer that fails to address the question. It could be a student in an exam (my case) or the politician's response to a journalist's question that they would rather avoid.

Comment: **Q:** Why are you home late?   **A:** I thought I would cook supper tonight dear.

Comment: Distracting? that attracts (the attention) away from its original focus.

Comment: I looked there but the best answers have other unwanted connotations...and others like Prevarication or Dissimulation imply a will to mislead (when the reason that the respondent is equivocating may be because they wish to hide their ignorance of the answer, or because they are buying time perhaps to formulate the answer in a more palatable way)

Comment: ...Obfuscation...eureka!

Comment: An "intent to divert to other topics" **is** deceitful.

Comment: I've said it before and I say it again: The word is [**nonanswer**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonanswer). @spook: 'Obfuscation' is not even in the ballpark.

Comment: Probably :**vague**

Comment: If not for the single-word tag, I'd suggest "half answer".

Answer (score 6):

**Prevaricate**

> : to avoid telling the truth by not directly answering a question - *[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prevaricate)*

Hence the noun: ***prevarication***.

or

**Equivocate**

> : to use unclear language especially to deceive or mislead someone.
>   -*[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equivocate)*

thus: ***equivocation***

Comment: "It's no use prevaricating around the bush, Grommit"

Answer (score 2):

One could say he **sidestepped** the question. That does not seem to have nearly as negative a connotation as *prevaricating, obfuscating, dissembling, or evading*.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have spent the whole morning preparing a meal for your girlfriend. When you are sitting at the table, you ask her 
whether she thinks it is good, but when she tries it, she discovers that it tastes terribly. Maybe she doesn't want to lie, but she doesn't want 
to utterly crush you either, so she could say "well, it is something different..." while going poker-faced. If you want to convey something like that, perhaps you can say:

> her answer was ***noncommittal***

Answer (score 1):

Is *"[to elude](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/elude) a question"* what you are looking for?

> - (transitive) To evade, or escape from someone or something, especially by using cunning or skill.
> - (transitive) To shake off a pursuer; to give someone the slip.
> - (transitive) To escape understanding of; to be incomprehensible to.

*"To elude a question"* will have the meaning of avoid to answer it.

---

This [post on wordreference](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/elude-evade-a-question.2293256/) ask about *"evade or elude a question"*.

An answer is

> He asked me about my private life. So I gave him an evasive answer.

And

> He evaded the question

So, I think that may serve your intent as well as *"**to evade** a question"*

Answer (score 1):

I rather like **parry** which [Merriam-Webster defines](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parry) as -

*: to avoid giving a direct answer to (a question) by being skillful or clever*

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps "Obfuscate" works here. From the Oxford English dictionary (OED):

> To render something unclear, obscure, or confused; to use obscure or impenetrable language.

The element of deliberate evasiveness is given in an OED example:

> He, along with his four companions, had lied and blocked and *obfuscated* in their statements to the court.

Comment: This answer has been edited to address comments. Please explain downvotes!